# ¿Cómo encuentro el comando que dispara una aplicación?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

Pongamos por ejemplo que quiero que 'monitor del sistema' se dispare a una hora determinada.
Iría a crontab y .... ¿Que nombre pongo?
me ha pasado ya más de una vez que he necesitado saber el comando que disparaba una aplicación y he tenido que bucear mucho por internet para averiguarlo.
Estoy buscando una solución mas general, ¡¡En algún lugar del S.O. podré ver el comando que dispara una aplicación que tengo instalada en mi S.O.!! ¿No?

Comment: Puedes ver los procesos activos con con el comando "ps aux". Abrir el programa, y volver a ver los procesos activos otra vez, habrá aparecido uno o más procesos nuevos y ahi puedes ver el comando y los parámetros con que se han ejecutado.

Comment: De momento este comentario es la mejor respuesta, pero tiene que haber algún sitio donde pueda ver como funciona un programa que me acabo de instalar. Lo que yo busco debería estar (pero no lo encuentro) en 'Gestor de software'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado una solución,
pero espero encontrar otra mejor, más genérica.

Consiste en mirar las propiedades del proceso que se esta ejecutando, en mi caso las que me muestra el monitor del sistema de Linix-mint.

Esta me vale para linux-mint y es un buen pundo de partida para buen punto de partida para otros casos pero no es exactamente lo que buscaba.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Abre una consola de comandos y ejecuta which comando

Comment: Esta muy interesante, pero... el problema es que no se que comando poner.
por ejemplo, yo tengo visualStudioCode y quiero averugar el comando (Ya se que es 'code' por que lo he buscado por internet) pero si no lo se, no adelanto nada con poner which visualStudioCode

Comment: Linux tiene una opción de autocompletar muy útil en terminal: puedes poner las dos o tres primeras palabras de un comando y dar al tab para que autocomplete... Si varios comandos comienzan con las mismas letras, un segundo tab arrojará todos los comandos coincidentes.

Comment: El ejemplo que te pongo es muy ilustrativo, por que si yo me bajo un programa que se llama visualStudioCode, intuitivamente pruebo con visual , le doy a tabulación... y no obtengo nada.
¿En serio no hay un sitio a mano donde ver que comando dispara que aplicación?

Comment: Generalmente el paquete trae un fichero de texto README.txt, acaso ahí te diga cómo ejecutar el programa en consola. Y si no, en la web del programa

Comment: Y si usas el gestor de software ¿Dónde encuentras el README.txt ?

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución que acabo de encontrar es buscar en /usr/share/applications hay se suelen poner los lanzadores, una vez hay buscar por el nombre el que piensas que puede ser el lanzador de la aplicación que buscas.
Por ejemplo: yo he ejecutado

```
find -name '*monit*
```

y he encontrado

```
./gnome-system-monitor-kde.desktop
./gnome-system-monitor.desktop
```

y a partir de hay, pues ensayo y Error.